# how to give relative path of local filesystem in pl/sql block

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, relative-path

I am trying to insert a clob from a xml file which is in my local file system. Below is the piece of pl/sql block.

```
declare
    xmlClobFile BFILE := BFILENAME(BFILE_DIR, 'clob.xml');
    tempClob CLOB;
begin
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY BFILE_DIR AS '||''''||'/home/abc/data/emp/clobs'||''''

--CLOB INSERT
DBMS_LOB.createtemporary(tempClob, TRUE);
DBMS_LOB.open(xmlClobFile, DBMS_LOB.lob_readonly);
DBMS_LOB.loadfromfile(tempClob, xmlClobFile, DBMS_LOB.lobmaxsize);


EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'insert into emp_data (id, clob_data) values (1000, :1)' using tempClob;
end;
/
```

Here when I give absolute path (/home/abc/data/emp/clobs) it works. But when I give relative path(like data/emp/clobs) and run this sql from /home/abc, it doesn't work.

```
  [exec] ERROR at line 1:
 [exec] ORA-22285: non-existent directory or file for FILEOPEN operation
 [exec] ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_LOB", line 937
 [exec] ORA-06512: at line 57
```

How to provide a relative path here, as I want this to be run in any machine and not just mine.

Answer (score 2):

The relative path, if anything will derive from the directory that the Oracle "start" command was run, e.g. /home/oracle. One way to test this, and to verify that relative paths will work (not used them myself) is to create a directory pointing to ".", and run the test to create a file, then search for that file. The directory you find the find in will be your start path. However, I think this is unsafe, since Oracle could be started from any folder (potentially), depending on if its autostarted, or whichever DBA was on hand to start it.

Answer (score 0):

It must be like this one:

```
xmlClobFile BFILE := BFILENAME('BFILE_DIR', 'clob.xml');
```

Comment: It didn't work. The absolute path worked with the above mentioned code. but I need it to be worked with relative path instead